# useEffect only updates DOM on subsequent update

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm new to React and I find useEffect's behavior a little confusing. I've written a simple hangman game (where the user tries to guess a word or phrase one letter at a time). I made a useEffect hook to update the board with each guess (generated by user input), and count wrong guesses.

Weirdly, the DOM only updates on subsequent updates. For example, say the user guesses 'T', then 'X'. Only after the 'X' guess will the board populate with all the 'Ts'.

Even stranger, when I add a random variable that increases by 1 each time useEffect runs, it works as expected.

For my own learning, I want to understand why this is happening, and how to resolve it in a not hacky way.

Below is my code - let me know if I'm missing any information.
Game.jsx

```
import Board from './Board'
import Input from './Input'
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react'

export default function Game() {
    const answer = ['I', 'F', ' ', 'T', 'H', 'E', 'R', 'E', 'S', ' ', 'A', ' ', 'W', 'I', 'L', 'L', ' ', 'T', 'H', 'E', 'R', 'E', 'S', ' ', 'A', ' ', 'W', 'A', 'Y']
    const [board, setBoard] = useState(new Array(answer.length).fill(' '))
    const [guess, setGuess] = useState('')
    const [count, setCount] = useState(0)
    const [state, setState] = useState(0)
    let newBoard = board

    useEffect(() => {
        let miss = true
        setState(state + 1) // hack to make useeffect work correctly
        answer.map((letter, index) => {
            if (guess == letter) {
                newBoard[index] = letter
                miss = false
            }
        })
        if (miss) { setCount(count + 1) }
        setBoard(newBoard)  
    }, [guess])

    return(
        <> 
            <Input guess={guess} setGuess={setGuess} />
            <Board board={board} answer={answer} />
        </>
    );
}
```

Input.jsx

```
import { useRef, useState } from "react";

export default function Input(props) {
    const inputRef = useRef();

    const handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        props.setGuess(inputRef.current.value.toUpperCase())      
    }

    return (
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            <input 
                type="text"
                ref={inputRef}
                placeholder="Make a guess"
                maxLength="1"
            />
            <button type="submit">Enter</button>
        </form>
    );
}
```

Board.jsx

```
import Box from './Box'
import './assets/Board.css'

export default function Board(props) {
    const board = props.board
    const answer = props.answer

    return (
        <div className='board'>
            {board.map((letter, index) => <Box key={index} value={letter} isSpace={answer[index] == ' '} />)}
        </div>
    );
}
```

Box.jsx

```
import './assets/Box.css'

export default function Box(props) {
    const value = props.value
    const isSpace = props.isSpace

    return (
        <div className={`box ${isSpace && ' is-space'}`}>{value}</div>
    )
}
```

Comment: Please show your full component, including the `return`.

Comment: looks like you want your effect to run in response to a user event, like a click. In that case, you should be using an event handler and not an effect. read https://react.dev/learn/you-might-not-need-an-effect

Comment: updated my question with more code!

Comment: We'll need an [mre]. Please add the Board.

Comment: Thanks for the quick replies - I added all the relevant code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here is that when you are calling setBoard(newBoard) in your useEffect, newBoard contains a reference to your board state. Even when you update a value stored at a particular index, the reference is unchanged, and without a reference to a new value React won't know that it needs to re-render. The most simple fix for this is just to use the spread operator when setting your state in your use effect:

```
setBoard([...newBoard]);
```

This way you're setting the board state to an entirely new array, which will trigger a rerender.

The `setState(state + 1)` call forces your code to work because with that line React does see a state update, and so it understands it needs to rerender.

It is true though that you don't need to use a useEffect here, at least as your code currently stands. Rather than setting a guess state (which it doesn't seem you're currently using other than to trigger this useEffect), you could create the following handler in your `Game` component:

```
const handleGuess = (guess) => {
  let miss = true;
  answer.forEach((letter, index) => {
    if (guess == letter) {
      newBoard[index] = letter
      miss = false
    }
  })
  if (miss) {
    setCount(count + 1);
  }
  setBoard([...newBoard]);
}

return (
  <> 
     <Input handleGuess={handleGuess} />
     <Board board={board} answer={answer} />
  </>
)
```

And then in your Input component, your `handleSubmit` method could look like this:

```
const handleSubmit = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  handleGuess(inputRef.current.value.toUpperCase())
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That was my issue - the answers below are correct as well, but this was the only one that answered the question.

Comment: So my working demo has no value?  This answer does not mention the wrong use of  useEffect tho.

Comment: @0stone0 I don't think they were saying that your working demo had no value, just that they were trying to learn why their attempt to change the state was not triggering the rerender they expected (in addition to how to improve their code). I also expanded my answer to include a better alternative to using useEffect here.

Comment: It had tremendous value @0stone0. I appreciate that you even styled it. My one qualm was that you never explained why it worked. If my goal was to have working code, that would be fine.. But I really wanted to understand this issue occurred.

Answer (score 1):

You should not use a `useEffect` to process such a change.

You can define a custom function that will call the `set***` when needed.

Please see the new `onGuess` function in the below demo:

```js
const { useState, useEffect, useRef } = React;

function Game() {
    const answer = ['I', 'F', ' ', 'T', 'H', 'E', 'R', 'E', 'S', ' ', 'A', ' ', 'W', 'I', 'L', 'L', ' ', 'T', 'H', 'E', 'R', 'E', 'S', ' ', 'A', ' ', 'W', 'A', 'Y']
    const [board, setBoard] = useState(new Array(answer.length).fill(' '))
    const [guess, setGuess] = useState('')
    const [count, setCount] = useState(0)
    const [state, setState] = useState(0)
    let newBoard = board

    const onGuess = (g) => {
      const boardCopy = [ ...board ];
      
      setState(s => s + 1);
      
      let miss = true;
      answer.forEach((a, i) => {
          if (g === a) {
              boardCopy[i] = a;
              miss = false;
          }
      });
      
      if (miss) {
          setCount(c => c + 1);
      }
      
      setBoard(boardCopy);
    }
    
    return(
        <React.Fragment> 
            <Input guess={guess} setGuess={onGuess} />
            <Board board={board} answer={answer} />
        </React.Fragment>
    );
}

function Input(props) {
    const inputRef = useRef();

    const handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        props.setGuess(inputRef.current.value.toUpperCase())      
    }

    return (
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            <input 
                type="text"
                ref={inputRef}
                placeholder="Make a guess"
                maxLength="1"
            />
            <button type="submit">Enter</button>
        </form>
    );
}

function Board(props) {
    const board = props.board;
    const answer = props.answer;

    return (
        <div className='board'>
            {board.map((letter, index) => <Box key={index} value={letter} isSpace={answer[index] == ' '} />)}
        </div>
    );
}

function Box(props) {
    const value = props.value
    const isSpace = props.isSpace

    return (
        <div className={`box ${(isSpace) && ' is-space'}`}>{value}</div>
    )
}

ReactDOM.render(<Game />, document.getElementById("react"));
```

```css
.board {
  display: flex;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.box { 
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

in the scenario you described, you don't need to useEffect, as setSate(useSate) is enough to update the state.
and also this code

```js
    useEffect(() => {
        let miss = true
        setState(state + 1) // hack to make useeffect work correctly
        answer.map((letter, index) => {
            if (guess == letter) {
                newBoard[index] = letter
                miss = false
            }
        })
        if (miss) { setCount(count + 1) }
        setBoard(newBoard)  
    }, [guess])
```

is a **very big mistake.**
It seems like you are trying to force a re-render by updating the state (setState(state + 1)) before performing the logic inside the useEffect. This is generally not a recommended practice. React will automatically trigger re-renders when state changes, so manually incrementing the state inside the useEffect is unnecessary and could lead to unexpected behavior.